# What's the best way to access env variables on the back end when using angular-fullstack generator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, yeoman, angular-fullstack

I'm using Yeoman's [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) generator.

And I have updated my **server/config/environment/local.env.js** file:

```js
module.exports = {
  DOMAIN: 'http://localhost:9000',
  SESSION_SECRET: 'vfsite2-secret',
  SENDGRID : {
      API_KEY : 'my_api_key'
  },
  DEBUG: ''
};
```

**How the best way can I use `SENDGRID.API_KEY` else where on my server files, for instance on my `server/api/thing/thing.controller.js` ?**

**Notice** this is **not** a duplicated question to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357821/how-do-you-access-environment-variables-on-the-front-end-when-using-yeomans-ang), because I want to use on server-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did to solve this issue:

Simplified **`server/config/environment/local.env.js`**:

```
module.exports = {
    DOMAIN: 'http://localhost:9000',
    SESSION_SECRET: 'vfsite2-secret',
    SENDGRID_API_KEY: 'my_api_key',
    DEBUG: ''
};
```

Updated my config file **`server/config/environment/index.js`**:

```
var all = {
  env: process.env.NODE_ENV,

  // ... other configs here

  // SendGrid connection options
  sendgrid: {
    'api_key': process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY
  }
};
```

Retrived my sendgrid api_key in my controller file **`server/api/thing/thing.controller.js`**:

```
import config from '../../config/environment';

// using SendGrid's Node.js Library
var sendgrid = require("sendgrid")(config.sendgrid.api_key);
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean global object?

```
global.globalConfig = {
  DOMAIN: 'http://localhost:9000',
  SESSION_SECRET: 'vfsite2-secret',
  SENDGRID : {
      API_KEY : 'my_api_key'
  },
  DEBUG: ''
};

module.exports = global.globalConfig;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. No. Not necessarily. I'm looking for the best way to use the environment variables in angular-fullstack.